Logstash-logback-encoder connection timeout while connecting to logstash from spring boot app
I am getting the following error during the start of my spring boot 3 application with "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.4"
01:53:14,051 |-WARN in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[LOGSTASH] - Log destination localhost/<unresolved>:5000: connection failed. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
at  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
at  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:539)
at  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:594)
at  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
at  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
at  at net.logstash.logback.appender.AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender$TcpSendingEventHandler.openSocket(AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender.java:765)
at  at net.logstash.logback.appender.AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender$TcpSendingEventHandler.onStart(AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender.java:691)
at  at net.logstash.logback.appender.AsyncDisruptorAppender$EventClearingEventHandler.onStart(AsyncDisruptorAppender.java:382)
at  at net.logstash.logback.encoder.com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.notifyStart(BatchEventProcessor.java:224)
at  at net.logstash.logback.encoder.com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:120)
at  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

My spring app is using 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docker-compose' dependency to manager docker-compose containers. Within the docker-compose I have ELK setup as follows
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.13.0
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"

  logstash:
    image: logstash:8.13.0
    command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
    ports:
      - "5000:5000" # Expose the default Logstash TCP input port
      - "9600:9600" # Expose the Logstash monitoring port
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config:/etc/logstash/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch


  kibana:
    image: kibana:8.13.0
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
      # - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      # - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=kibana_password # ${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:

The issue is only at the beginning of the spring application bootup. After spring-boot-docker-compose runs the logstash container, the appender tries to connect to logstash container and fails first time (because logstash needs to wait for elasticsearch to come up then start); then retries the connection every 30 seconds and is able to connect to the logstash server. Based on the documentation of logstash-logback-encoder - https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder?tab=readme-ov-file#connection-timeout I tried adding this connectionTimeout to my logback-spring.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="LOGSTASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>localhost:5000</destination>
        <connectionTimeout>60 seconds</connectionTimeout>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH"/>
    </root>
</configuration>

Spring is able to load the changes from the logback-spring.xml but the connectionTimeout alone isn't working. Does anyone know what I am missing?

I think you should simply add health check for elasticsearch and dependent services as explained here in official documentation.
Then you can add a condition as condition: service_healthy which ensures that logstash starts after healthy condition of elasticsearch.

I think the problem is "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.4" dependency of my spring app trying to connect to logstash server even before it is up. I need to make that dependency have some initialDelay before even trying to establish a connection OR make the connect timeout a bit longer.
